# How to insert multiple chosen MySQL columns to single PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

## Hello

I didn't find any solution on my problem with inserting multiple chosen **MySQL** Table Columns to single **PHP** array.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM zaznam,client WHERE zaznam.id_client=client.id_client 
AND zaznam.id_client=1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

---

**-Edit:** I need "zaznam.date", "zaznam.rozdil" and "client.limit", but not that id_client in WHERE parametr.

***This code insert into Array all columns of my table. But I want to reach solution, where I can insert into this array only some of the columns.***

I was trying around 3 hours to find any idea around this thing. Maybe I missed something, than if you **link** me the solution, it would be awesome too.

*I hope I put every information you need to help me out :)*

**Chosse**

Comment: You can specify the columns you want instead of using `*`.

Comment: select the columns you want in the sql not `*` (which is all)?

Comment: add required column name on your select query. it will optimized and you get rid from unnecessary columns on your array.

Comment: I need 3 specific columns, but I need to name the parametrs of WHERE too. So I need asomething like delete the WHERE parametrs before inserting the columns into array.

I need "zaznam.date", "zaznam.rozdil" and "client.limit", but not that id_client in WHERE parametr

Comment: _Delete where parameters before inserting into array_ I am lost with this sentence.. Are you saying you want further clauses? `AND col2 = 'this' AND col3 = 'that'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick SQL tutorial..

A table can have as many columns as you want it to have e.g. lets call this table `Users`

`ID    |    Name    |    Email    |    DateOfBirth`

you can select `ALL` records from this table by doing

`SELECT * FROM Users`

If you only want 1 column you need to name it

`SELECT Email FROM Users`

Lets add some data in

`ID    |    Name    |    Email            |    DateOfBirth`

`1     |    Test    |    test@example.com |    01/01/1990`

`2     |    Test2   |   test2@example.com |    01/01/1990`

If we want to only get the record with `ID = 2` then we use a `WHERE` clause

`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = 2`

We can then choose to only select certain columns and only look at the row where `ID = 2`

`SELECT Name, Email FROM Users WHERE ID = 2`

Just because I am using `ID` in the `WHERE` doesn't affect what I've SELECTED in the select

I could go on but really.. go back to the basics and learn SQL from a tutorial

For your particular query do this (personally, using `INNER JOIN` instead of `,` separated joins is better and easier to read - they are exactly the same however in terms of what they do):

```
SELECT zaznam.date, zaznam.rozdil, client.limit 
FROM   zaznam
INNER JOIN client ON zaznam.id_client = client.id_client 
WHERE  zaznam.id_client=1
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you <3
School sucks then :D

Answer (score 3):

Instead of selecting all columns (`SELECT *`), list the columns that you want after `SELECT` clause.

E.g.:

```
SELECT zaznam.id_client, zaznam.other_field, client.name, client.something_else 
FROM zaznam,client 
WHERE zaznam.id_client=client.id_client 
    AND zaznam.id_client=1
```

Comment: This will select 4 columns with "id_client" as parametr of WHERE clause. But I need 3 specific columns without the "id_client" one, which I put into PHP array.

Comment: @ChosseMartiny just don't select it. Have you even googled about sql and learnt it? Pretty much step 1 is learning a select statement `SELECT zaznam.date, zaznam.rozdil, client.limit FROM ...`

Comment: I learnt, that in SELECT clause have to be named even columns of WHERE clause.

E.g.: "SELECT date FROM zaznam WHERE id_client=1" wont work.

Comment: Think you need to go back and have another look. If you don't add `id_client` to the SELECT list, it won't be returned whether you have it in the WHERE clause or not. The SELECT list does _not_ need to list all or any of the columns that are in the WHERE clause.

Comment: OK, I'll try ^^

Comment: Yeah, I've put that field on the list just as an example. You're free to select fields that you want.